# How to convert a string to a user defined ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a comma separated string of student values that I need to add to an ArrayList of Students. However, what I currently have doesn't work and I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
String s;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
s = in.readLine();
ArrayList<Student> slist = new ArrayList<>();
while (s != null){
    slist.add(s);
    s = in.readLine();
}
```

The `slist.add(s)` does not work as the String, s, cannot be converted to an ArrayList

Comment: Your `ArrayList` is of `Student` type and you are trying to add `String` type data in to it. See the problem ?

Comment: `s` doesn't need to be converted to an `ArrayList`. It needs to be converted to a `Student`. Without the code for `Student`, it is hard to say how to do that.

Comment: `add(s)` returns boolean Type. It cannot be added to `slist` as it is of Type `ArrayList<Student>`. It only works if the `ArrayList` is of type `String`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see what I was doing wrong. Pretty silly of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how you posted no code on how to create a student this would be my best guess on how to fix your problem.

```
String s;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
s = in.readLine();
ArrayList<Student> slist = new ArrayList<>();
while (s != null){
    slist.add(new Student(s)); //creat a new student based on the string
    s = in.readLine();
}
```

This will work if you have a constructor for the Student class that takes a String as a parameter. Like everyone has stated you are creating an ArrayList of Students and not Strings. You must create a Student object if you want to add it to your list.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your ArrayList accepts elements of type `Student`, but you are trying to add elements of type `String`.

Assuming your Student class is related to the strings you are trying to add such as the Students' name:

```
class Student{
    private String name;
    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then you can add it as:

```
while (s != null){
    slist.add(new Student(s));  //create student obj from s, then add to list
    s = in.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    private static class Student {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public Student(String line) {
            String[] parts = line.split(",");
            if (parts.length > 0 && parts.length == 2) {
                this.firstName = parts[0];
                this.lastName = parts[1];
            }
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public Student setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public Student setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }
    }

    private static final String fileName = "fileName.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        s = in.readLine();
        ArrayList<Student> slist = new ArrayList<>();

        while (s != null) {
            slist.add(new Student(s));
            s = in.readLine();
        }

        slist.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```